# Lightning - We couldn't retrieve the component in the main region

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, package, aura

I develop managed package, and I pack lightning page and lightning components into package. I have Mydomain established. It uploads successfully, but when I install it in target org, I get an error:

> (MyLightningPage) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s) There were
>   custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected
>   record(s). The first validation error encountered was "We couldn't
>   retrieve the Mymanespace:Mycomponent component in the main region.".

I can install package with lightning page without that Mycomponent successfully.
Component has only two inputs and button and it sends and receives data from Apex controller.

In development org component works absolutely alright.

Here is component code:

```
<aura:component controller="LoginCtrl" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <ui:inputText aura:id="login" label="Login" />
    <ui:inputSecret aura:id="password" label="Password" />
    <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.saveCredentials}" />
</aura:component>
```

Here is flexipage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>MyComponent</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>My Page</masterLabel>
    <pageTemplate>flexipage:defaultAppHomeTemplate</pageTemplate>
    <type>AppPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

I can see that in component definition namespace is missing, but when I add namespace: to component name and deploy it, after retriving it is again without namespace.

Comment: Have you ensured the component is global? You might post some of the markup, and some of the code where it is being called to help.

Comment: @Peter please check code

Comment: @Peter I added attribute  access="global" but I get again the same error. And I can install package is my Lightning app does not contain my lightning components.

Comment: @Peter and later in target org I can create new app and drag my components into it, and it will work. The issue is I cannot install package that already contains lightning page with components